# remove duplicates from sql union

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm doing some basic sql on a few tables I have, using a union(rightly or wrongly)

but I need remove the duplicates. Any ideas?

```
select * from calls
left join users a on calls.assigned_to= a.user_id
where a.dept = 4 
union
select * from calls
left join users r on calls.requestor_id= r.user_id
where r.dept = 4
```

Comment: Are you saying that your query does not remove duplicates?

Answer (score 222, accepted):

`Union` will remove duplicates. `Union All` does not.

Comment: this is true, at least for MS SQL.

Comment: Interesting...doesn't remove the duplicates on the above statement

Comment: @thegunner - Do you happen to have a Timestamp data type as one of your columns?

Comment: @thegunner - Union does in fact remove duplicates. I would remove the selct * from both queries and manually add columns one at a time, to both, until you find a case where you think a duplicate occurs. When you find one, what is the data type?

Comment: Hi, theres no timstamp. I'm just getting two duplicate rows

Comment: actually - on second look some columns have been added in that I wasnt; expection making the rows unique. I'll have another look at the query - thanks.

Comment: Hi Randy, yeah I've removed the * and just used columns that I wanted, the other was adding columns that I didn't want (from the users table) making the rows unique. So yeah sorted now. Thanks ;)

Comment: I concur. It does not in fact remove duplicates. I have a similar query and can see line duplicates.

Comment: I also extremly doubt that duplicates will be removed automatically using UNION on SQL Server. Is there any documentation for this alleged behavior?

Answer (score 6):

Using `UNION` automatically removes duplicate rows unless you specify `UNION ALL`:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: does this include duplicated rows returned by one of the 'unioned' queries?

Comment: @ZachSmith Yes, it seems it really does, and I've just been bitten by a related bug (with a Postgres DB), with which I was completely baffled by the fact that commenting out my second "unioned" sub-query resulted in _more_ rows, which seemed very weird to me.

Answer (score 4):

Others have already answered your direct question, but perhaps you could simplify the query to eliminate the question (or have I missed something, and a query like the following will really produce substantially different results?):

```
select * 
    from calls c join users u
        on c.assigned_to = u.user_id 
        or c.requestor_id = u.user_id
    where u.dept = 4
```

Comment: Be aware that OR in a Join will cause a table scan, not an ideal solution

Answer (score 4):

Since you are still getting duplicate using only `UNION` I would check that:

- That they are exact duplicates. I mean, if you make a

  `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (<your query>) AS subquery`

  you do get fewer files?
- That you don't have already the duplicates in the first part of the query (maybe generated by the left join). As I understand it `UNION` it will not add to the result set rows that are already on it, but it  won't remove duplicates already present in the first data set.

Comment: At least T-SQL removes all duplicates, even if they are coming from the same data set.

Comment: I was scratching my head and then I read your solution and checked.... 1 column wasn't same...hence, "Duplicate" rows...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using T-SQL then it appears from previous posts that UNION removes duplicates. But if you are not, you could use distinct. This doesn't quite feel right to me either but it could get you the result you are looking for

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM
(
select * from calls
left join users a on calls.assigned_to= a.user_id
where a.dept = 4 
union
select * from calls
left join users r on calls.requestor_id= r.user_id
where r.dept = 4
)a
```

Comment: this ain't working on my case. I still have 2 columns with the same data

Answer (score 0):

If you are using T-SQL you could use a temporary table in a stored procedure and update or insert the records of your query accordingly.

Comment: please make sure your answer provide more details, If you want to point to something you can use comments