# Avoid duplicate rows in UNION query with ORDER BY SortKey

Tags: sql, duplicates, union

I have UNION query that's need to be deduplicated :

```
SELECT *, 0 as SortKey
FROM house
WHERE door LIKE "green"
UNION
SELECT *, 1 as SortKey
FROM house
WHERE door LIKE "red"
ORDER BY sortkey ASC
```

UNION should de-duplicate rows but "0 as SortKey" and "1 as SortKey" made this impossible because I want to order this query by SortKey 0, than SortKey 1.

How could I get this query de-duplicated?

...

Maybe my example, was not enough well formed.
https://rextester.com/BUFGE49859
I need this result :

id  nom classement  SortKey

1   9946    blue river  1112    1

2   9945    blue house  1113    1

4   9944    red house   1114    3

5   9943    green house 1115    3

Avoid 9945 duplicate and preserve SortKey order.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Bit of a misleading title if you ask me.

Comment: I use PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: @TT I change the title

Answer (score 1):

You can just select all rows that match either condition and decide which SortKey to use with `CASE`. Depending on the DBMS you're using the syntax may differ.

```
SELECT *,
  CASE
    WHEN door LIKE "green" THEN 0
    WHEN door like "red" THEN 1
  END as SortKey
FROM house
WHERE door LIKE "green" or door LIKE "red"
ORDER BY SortKey
```

If you want duplicates to have 1 instead of 0 then just switch the order of the CASE statements.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT door, SortKey FROM (
    SELECT *, 0 as SortKey FROM house WHERE door LIKE 'green'
    UNION
    SELECT *, 1 as SortKey FROM house WHERE door LIKE 'red'
) a ORDER BY Sortkey ASC
```

#### Live example:

- https://rextester.com/NNKJ13229

#### Reference:

- [remove duplicates from sql union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127714/remove-duplicates-from-sql-union)