# How to join 2 tables (Table 2 data if present in Table 1, that specific record must not be selected) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables, `Table1` and `Table2`. Both tables have only 1 column `value`.

- `Table1` - `er3, 5ty, 5y6, 72j, 98e, sf1, 3mn, 9w2`
- `Table2` - `r5k, ad8, 5ty, sf1, 34x`

How can we query, so that we can get the below result.

Result: `er3, 5ty, 5y6, 72j, 98e, sf1, 3mn, 9w2, r5k, ad8,  34x`

I tried this code:

```
SELECT value 
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.value = T1.value
WHERE T2.value IS NOT NULL
```

This query is not returning the expected result.

Expected result: `er3, 5ty, 5y6, 72j, 98e, sf1, 3mn, 9w2, r5k, ad8,  34x`

`Table2` is the input param values, need to check with `Table1` values and if exist, must not include that value while joining as we already have that value in `Table 1`.

Thanks in advance

**Edit** - I have adopted Tim Biegeleisen's solution and it works fine. When union statement was assigned to a variable as below

```
SELECT @UpdatedValues = SELECT value FROM Table1 
UNION 
SELECT value FROM Table2
```

got the below error message.

Error Message - `Variable assignment is not allowed in a statement containing a top level UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator`.

I have to assign the result set to a variable. How can this be achieved. Thanks in advance.

**Edit (2)**

I have achieved the desired result taking *MartinSmith's* comments.

**Final SQL Query for my solution**

```
SELECT @UpdatedValues = STRING_AGG(d.value, ',')  
WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY value) 
FROM (SELECT value FROM Table1 UNION SELECT value FROM Table2) d
```

Comment: Use Union between the 2 tables

Comment: Try select distinct in your query in place of select. Also you don't need the where clause if there are no null values in the tables.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the assignment to `@UpdatedValues`? `SELECT value FROM Table1 UNION SELECT value FROM Table2` returns a table. So you can't sensibly assign it to a scalar variable. You can insert it to a table variable. Or do some aggregation to return a single value and then assign that to a scalar variable

Comment: @MartinSmith, Thanks for your comment. Actually I am doing `SELECT @UpdatedValues = STRING_AGG(value, ',')  WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY value) FROM Table1 UNION SELECT value FROM Table2`. Finally, aggregating for comma separated values in a variable. Thanks

Comment: You can put that into a derived table `SELECT @UpdatedValues = STRING_AGG(value, ',')  WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY value) FROM (SELECT value FROM Table1 UNION SELECT value FROM Table2) d`

Comment: @MartinSmith, Do we need to add alias `d` here -> STRING_AGG(`d`.value,..

Comment: Not required but you can do if you think it makes it clearer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove duplicates from sql union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127714/remove-duplicates-from-sql-union)

Comment: @MartinSmith, Thank You so much. I am able to achieve the desired result. Thank You :)

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi, No. It does not answer my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one I think there is no need to join them

```
;WITH test AS(
  SELECT value FROM Table1 UNION ALL
  SELECT value FROM Table2
)

SELECT DISTINCT value FROM test
```

Comment: Never use *, especially when using `UNION`. You are on high risk to get an error message because the number of columns doesn't match.

Comment: @JonasMetzler Or the number of columns matches, but the _types_ do not match.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want a *union* of the two tables:

```sql
SELECT [value] FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT [value] FROM Table2;
```

Comment: Value is a reserved key word. Use it between brackets or don't use it at all (to follow the best practices of naming conventions

Comment: @Earth Any reason for unaccepting my answer?

Comment: I remember I wrote an article about that, I spend one hour daily on SOF and sometimes more to understand and try to simulate the OP question on my machine and it ends up with ghosting me or thank you it worked without validating :https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/unseen-realm-stack-overflow-comedy-errors-amira-bedhiafi%3FtrackingId=iTX0nPcZp93oUMHTz0B6vw%253D%253D/?trackingId=iTX0nPcZp93oUMHTz0B6vw%3D%3D